# Combined Word Count for Files in Directories

Tags: wc

Is it possible to return a combined word count with `wc` only for certain files (like .txt files, for example) in a series of directories?

Comment: `cat` them all and pipe the result to `wc` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU wc (at least), you can combine the results of `find` with `wc` as such:

```
find folder/ -name '*.txt' -print0 |   wc -w --files0-from=-
```

This gives you all the power of `find` (a bit overkill if you just want to find all files ending with `.txt` to be honest) and it handles even the strangest filenames (containing newlines for example).

Comment: On MacOS, you can replace `wc` with `gwc` (after you have installed `coreutils` with `brew install coreutils`).

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand your situation correctly? So, you're saying that you are in a folder say Documents, and you have several folders within this folder, so you change directory (cd) into that directory an want to count how many .txt files are deep into that directory in every sub-folder?

If that's what you mean, then this is how you do it:

```
$ ls -R *.txt | wc -l
```

ls = list.
-R = recursively every subfolder
*.txt = any number of any character ending in .txt

| = pass to.

wc -l = count how many.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. The `*.txt` would be expanded by the shell into a space delimited list of .txt files found in the current working directory. If no .txt files exist, `ls` would likely (depending on shell options) get passed `*.txt`, but since `ls` doesn't do pattern matching, it would be looking for a file litterarly called `*.txt` in the current working directory.

Comment: See [how bash processes commands](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_04.html#sect_01_04_01_01) and [file name expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_07). `ls *.txt` is generally equivlient to `echo *.txt`. The shell is doing the expansion first, `ls` is essentially just printing the result.

Comment: Oh, so what the asker wanted was the number of lines in every text file recursively, and not the number of text files recursively?

Comment: Yes, but the `*.txt` is processed, before the `ls -R`. Your command doesn't count the number of .txt files recursivly. It counts the number of .txt files in the current working directory and fails on some edge cases. `ls -R | grep .txt | wc -l` would be closer, but again doesn't handle newlines well, etc... [lgeorget's awnser](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353873/60101) does

Comment: I guess as a better example, consider that you have two subdirectories called `1abc` and `2abc`. `ls -R *abc` wouldn't print files ending in `abc`, it would recursivly print everything found in `1abc` and `2abc`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good one-liner via xargs I just made - tested on macOS:

```
find . | grep -E "(.*\.js.*|.*\.txt|.*\.css|.*\.htm.*|.*\.sh|.*\.scss|.*\.md|.*\.java|.*\.conf|.*\.yaml)" | sed "s/^/\"/" | sed "s/$/\"/" | xargs -J thefile wc thefile
```

This handles spaces in filenames. Maybe swap -J for -Y in Linux? Lawn mower cut my Ethernet to my linux box so I can't test there presently.